# pyqt5 vertical scrollbar events?

Tags: pyqt5

What is the correct name of the signal to capture vertical scrollbar events from QTextEdit. I've got:

```
textEdit.verticalScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(setScrollBarPos)
```

...

```
def setScrollBarPos():
    scrollBarPos = textEdit.verticalScrollBar.value()
```

Python complains with the following message:
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'valueChanged'

I'm trying to save the last vertical scroll position so when the user switches in and out of the text edit box, I can set it to that position.

Comment: `verticalScrollBar()`.

Comment: typo, change `verticalScrollBar` to `verticalScrollBar()`.

Answer (score 0):

use

```py
textEdit.verticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollBarPos)
```

It worked for me